# Draw in the screen corner with canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I want to draw some text inside my layout that is full screen the problem is i can get an accurate point. Here is what i coded:

```
 DisplayMetrics display = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                    int width = display.widthPixels;
                    String data_azi = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()); 
                    cnv.drawText(data_azi, width - p.measureText(data_azi), 40,p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to measure upfront and use that measurement during drawing time. For example you could call `measureText()` at init time. This method measures the width of the current date and adds 20% to the measured width.

```
private final Rect mBounds = new Rect();
private final Date mDate = new Date();


private void measureText(final Paint p){
    final String dummy =  DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(mDate);
    p.getTextBounds(dummy, 0, dummy.length(), mBounds);
    final int inset = (int) (mBounds.width()*0.1f); //add safety margin
    mBounds.inset(-inset, 0);
}
```

Then you draw like this:

```
mDate.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
String data_azi = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(mDate); 
cnv.drawText(data_azi, width - mBounds.width(), mBounds.height(),p);
```

Also make sure that your paint object is left aligned `p.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);`